# How can I resolve a connection issue between MySQL and Spring Boot in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Currently, I am working on a Kubernetes project for my school project. Previously, I developed a web application using Next.js, Spring Boot, and MySQL about six months ago. I am now attempting to integrate this application with Kubernetes. Initially, I created an image for each component and tested it using "docker run" successfully. However, I am encountering difficulties in translating this to Kubernetes.

The error message I am receiving on the Spring Boot pod is:

`Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure.`

I understand that this error is usually due to issues when connecting to MySQL such as a missing database or an incorrect URL. Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Here is a sample of the YAML file I am using to create the MySQL and Spring Boot pods.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: lost_island

# lost_island_mysql

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
  namespace: lost_island
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lost_island_mysql
  namespace: lost_island
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:latest
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: 1234
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: lost_island
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              value: 1234
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
  namespace: lost_island
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - name: mysql-port
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  type: NodePort

# lost_island_backend

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lost_island_backend
  namespace: lost_island
  labels:
    app: springboot
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: springboot
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: springboot
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: springboot-app
          image: skull/lost_island_backend
          env:
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              value: jdbc:mysql://mysql-service.lost_island.svc.cluster.local:3306/lost_island?serverTimezone=UTC&sessionVariables=sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&useSSL=false
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
              value: root
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
              value: 1234
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 9092
```

Comment: Scanning through this, the parts seem right to me: `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` points at the Service name, and the Service `selector:` matches the database pod `labels:`.  (I might use a StatefulSet and not a Deployment for the database, and avoid manually constructing the PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim, but I think this is secondary to your issue.)  Is the database Pod actually starting up?  Is there more to the error message that suggests what might be failing?

Answer (score 0):

1. with in same namespace `lost_island`

app backend deployment below value suffice

`value: jdbc:mysql://mysql-service:3306/lost_island?serverTimezone=UTC&sessionVariables=sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&useSSL=false`

2. open container port `3306` in mysql deployment specs

Comment: Thank you for your message. I just wanted to clarify something about point 2. Could you please provide more what i need to change? I apologize for any confusion, as I am not very experienced with Kubernetes.

Comment: you can also check `kubectl get pods -n lost_island`
verify mysql pod status running